# I cant get monitor mode in airmon-ng in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, aircrack-ng, airmon-ng

I type `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` but I cant enable monitor mode. I use Ubuntu 17.04.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your wireless interface indeed wlan0? Confirm: `iwconfig`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the exact output of the command you ran? We can't know what might be going on without seeing the error message. Thanks.

Comment: yes in the past it was wlp2s0 but now wlan0.  how fix it?

Comment: i typed ifconfig then i get

lo and wlan0

Comment: Does it work if you put the interface in monitor mode first? `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` followed by `sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor`

Comment: when I typed "sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor" i can see 

"Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
"

how fix it